# Clipboard copy action - whose file is the content?

Tags: windows, linux, copy, clipboard, paste

I need to track copy-paste actions in Windows and Linux (I'm assuming gnome/unity) towards my app monitoring the clipboard content and **the originating file's location (path)**

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think the clipboard provides that kind of information. Even if it did you'd only get the application name, not the file that the application has open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipboard transfers contain data, not metadata.  They may not be a "file" at all.  If you want a standard GUI metaphor for moving files around, maybe you could consider Drag & Drop.

Comment: Thank you, I have now another question but it's better to close this one first